# how do I remove-Printer that contains wildcard characters through Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to remove printers with the Remove-printer command, but keep running into a WildcardPatternException error. The printer name contains [].

This is the error that I am getting when running the command.

Exception calling "FilterByProperty" with "4" argument(s): "The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid:

```
[Follow_Me_Colour_Duplex [ServerName](Mobility)]"
At line:1153 char:9
+         $__cmdletization_queryBuilder.FilterByProperty('Name', $__cmd ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WildcardPatternException
```

Despite the server name being in the printer name, it is a **local printer**.

Is there a way to ignore the wildcard characters in this string? Or is there another way to get the location / name without the characters being in there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to about_Wildcards - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.4 - you can escape special **wildcard** characters with a backtick, *but* since the backtick is itself a special character in PowerShell strings you need use two, so try ```Remove-Printer "``[Follow_Me_Colour_Duplex -Name ``[ServerName``]``(Mobility``)``]"```...

Comment: This sorted the problem. Thanks so much.